# RNN Regression with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, floating-point, deep-learning, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a simple RNN to predict values of a 3-shifted sequence. I have used [Siraj Raval's code](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Use-Tensorflow-for-Time-Series-Live-) a little bit. Basically, his code works as a binary classification problem but I want to use the similar RNN approach for floating number sequence. However, I am getting horrible results even for the binary input, floating output after I have removed the softmax and argmax functions in the final layer. However, results are almost static (around 0.43296~). Here is the final code.

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML 
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_epochs = 200
total_series_length = 50000
truncated_backprop_length = 40
state_size = 4
num_classes = 1
echo_step = 3
batch_size = 10
num_batches = total_series_length//batch_size//truncated_backprop_length

#Step 1 - Collect data
#Now generate the training data, 
#the input is basically a random binary vector. The output will be the 
#“echo” of the input, shifted echo_step steps to the right.

def generateData():
    #0,1, 50K samples, 50% chance each chosen
    x = np.array(np.random.choice(2, total_series_length, p=[0.5, 0.5]))
    #shift 3 steps to the left
    y = np.roll(x, echo_step)
    #padd beginning 3 values with 0
    y[0:echo_step] = 0
    #Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.
    #The reshaping takes the whole dataset and puts it into a matrix, 
    #that later will be sliced up into these mini-batches.
    x = x.reshape((batch_size, -1))  # The first index changing slowest, subseries as rows
    y = y.reshape((batch_size, -1))

    return (x, y)

#Step 2 - Build the Model

#datatype, shape (5, 15) 2D array or matrix, batch size shape for later
batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, truncated_backprop_length])

#and one for the RNN state, 5,4 
init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, state_size])

#3 layer recurrent net, one hidden state

#randomly initialize weights
W = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size+1, state_size), dtype=tf.float32)
#anchor, improves convergance, matrix of 0s 
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1,state_size)), dtype=tf.float32)

W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(state_size, num_classes),dtype=tf.float32)
b2 = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1,num_classes)), dtype=tf.float32)

# Unpack columns
#Unpacks the given dimension of a rank-R tensor into rank-(R-1) tensors.
#so a bunch of arrays, 1 batch per time step
inputs_series = tf.unstack(batchX_placeholder, axis=1)
labels_series = tf.unstack(batchY_placeholder, axis=1)


#Forward pass
#state placeholder
current_state = init_state
#series of states through time
states_series = []


#for each set of inputs
#forward pass through the network to get new state value
#store all states in memory
for current_input in inputs_series:
    #format input
    current_input = tf.reshape(current_input, [batch_size, 1])
    #mix both state and input data 
    input_and_state_concatenated = tf.concat([current_input, current_state],1 )  # Increasing number of columns
    #perform matrix multiplication between weights and input, add bias
    #squash with a nonlinearity, for probabiolity value
    next_state = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(input_and_state_concatenated, W) + b)  # Broadcasted addition
    #store the state in memory
    states_series.append(next_state)
    #set current state to next one
    current_state = next_state

#calculate loss
#second part of forward pass
#logits short for logistic transform
print(states_series)
logits_series = [tf.matmul(state, W2) + b2 for state in states_series] #Broadcasted addition
#apply softmax nonlinearity for output probability
predictions_series =logits_series # [tf.nn.softmax(logits) for logits in logits_series] # 

#measure loss, calculate softmax again on logits, then compute cross entropy
#measures the difference between two probability distributions
#this will return A Tensor of the same shape as labels and of the same type as logits 
#with the softmax cross entropy loss.
print("Logits",logits_series)
print("Labels",labels_series)
losses = [tf.squared_difference(labels,logits) for logits, labels in zip(logits_series,labels_series)]
#computes average, one value
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(total_loss)


    #Step 3 Training the network
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #we stupidly have to do this everytime, it should just know
    #that we initialized these vars. v2 guys, v2..
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    #interactive mode
    plt.ion()
    #initialize the figure
    plt.figure()
    #show the graph
    plt.show()
    #to show the loss decrease
    loss_list = []

    for epoch_idx in range(num_epochs):
        #generate data at eveery epoch, batches run in epochs
        #x,y = simple_differential_data(1,1,total_series_length)
        x,y = generateData()
        #initialize an empty hidden state
        _current_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))

        print("New data, epoch", epoch_idx)
        #each batch
        for batch_idx in range(num_batches):
            #starting and ending point per batch
            #since weights reoccuer at every layer through time
            #These layers will not be unrolled to the beginning of time, 
            #that would be too computationally expensive, and are therefore truncated 
            #at a limited number of time-steps
            start_idx = batch_idx * truncated_backprop_length
            end_idx = start_idx + truncated_backprop_length

            batchX = x[:,start_idx:end_idx]
            batchY = y[:,start_idx:end_idx]

            #run the computation graph, give it the values
            #we calculated earlier
            _total_loss, _train_step, _current_state, _predictions_series = sess.run(
                [total_loss, train_step, current_state, predictions_series],
                feed_dict={
                    batchX_placeholder:batchX,
                    batchY_placeholder:batchY,
                    init_state:_current_state
                })

            loss_list.append(_total_loss)

            if batch_idx%100 == 0:
                print("Step",batch_idx, "Loss", _total_loss)


print(_predictions_series)
print(batchY)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with printing the input after batching.

I ran your code with a batch size of 1 and loss seems to go down quickly (Step 500 Loss 0.000245932).

The fact that that does not happen with a larger batch size suggests that there could be a bug in how the input is sliced / transposed.